# using animated buttons in portfolio

Tags: html, css

I included animated buttons in my html file, but i dont know how to use them with my portfolio.
I have tried more animated buttons, but the problem is i dont know how to use them in my portfolio code. I think it is just a declaraon and calling problem.

```css
.dc-morph-btns {
  position:absolute; 
  left:50%;
  top:-20%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    width:500px;
  height:150px;
    font-size: 1.4em; 
    line-height: 0.9em; 
    color: #444; 
    text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.dc-morph-btns li {  
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    overflow: visible;

}

.dc-morph-btns li a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #6BABDC;
    text-indent:0;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 70px;
    height:70px;
    transition: all 500ms, border-radius 500ms,  cubic-bezier(0.190,1.000,0.220,1.000);
    border-radius: 50%;
}


.dc-morph-btns li a:hover {
    border: 1px solid #6BABDC;
  width: 70px;
    height:70px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.dc-morph-btns ul li i {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin: -13px 0 0 -18px;
    color: #6BABDC;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    z-index: 2;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.dc-morph-btns ul li span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    bottom: -40px;
    left:-5px;
    display: block;
    color: #6BABDC;
    opacity:0;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;

}

.dc-morph-btns ul li:hover span {
    color: #6BABDC;
    opacity:1;
}

.dc-morph-btns ul li.selected span {
    color: #5181A6;
    opacity:1;
}

.dc-morph-btns ul li.selected:hover span {
    color: #6BABDC;
    opacity:1;

}

.dc-morph-btns li.selected a{  
    border: 1px solid #6BABDC;
  background: #6BABDC;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-top-left-radius:40px;
    border-top-right-radius:2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:40px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);

}
.dc-morph-btns li i{ 
    color: #6BABDC;
}
.dc-morph-btns li.selected i{ 
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dc-morph-btns">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#games"></a><i class="icon-layers"></i><span>All</span></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#applications"></a> <i class="icon-camera"></i><span>Photos</span></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#all"></a><i class="icon-cog"></i><span>Settings</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <section class="work">
                <figure class="games">
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nebulaxgames.pidgeonpooper&hl=sl"> <img src="https://raw.github.com/Fellini85/picture/master/1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <dl> <dt>nebulaXgames</dt>
                            <dd>Pigeon Pooper</dd> <dt>Role</dt>
                            <dd>game</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </a>
                </figure>
                <figure class="games">
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lightningbolt.tumblingball&hl=sl"> <img src="https://raw.github.com/Fellini85/picture/master/1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <dl> <dt>nebulaXgames</dt>
                            <dd>Tumbling Ball</dd> <dt>Role</dt>
                            <dd>game</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </a>
                </figure>
                <figure class="applications">
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nebulaxgames.nebulaxplanner&hl=sl"> <img src="https://raw.github.com/Fellini85/picture/master/1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <dl> <dt>nebulaXgames</dt>
                            <dd>Nebula X Planner</dd> <dt>Role</dt>
                            <dd>application</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </a>
                </figure>
                <figure class="games">
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lightningbolt.fatlegend&hl=sl"> <img src="https://raw.github.com/Fellini85/picture/master/1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <dl> <dt>nebulaXgames</dt>
                            <dd>Fat Legend</dd> <dt>Role</dt>
                            <dd>game</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </a>
                </figure>
                <figure class="games">
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lightningbolt.jumping.flea&hl=sl"> <img src="https://raw.github.com/Fellini85/picture/master/1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <dl> <dt>nebulaXgames</dt>
                            <dd>Jumping Flea</dd> <dt>Role</dt>
                            <dd>game</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, or what could possibly your problem. I also have no idea for what reason someone would upvote this question.

Comment: i added animated buttons in my code but they don't work because i dont know how to use the buttons, in my portfolio code i have the figures declared  <figure class="applications"> ... and in my buttons i have this code --> <a href="#games"></a><i class="icon-layers"></i><span>All</span></li> i dont know how to add my figures in the button code that when i click on the button something hapens

Comment: So your problem is not related to anything visual, but you're trying to figure out how to add functionality to your buttons? In that case, you're wading in broad waters regarding SO questions, but if you want to give it a shot, you should state what you want to happen. After all, you're dealing with `a` elements with href attributes, which have default functionality - they link.

Comment: yes! the visual thing is working just i dont know how to add the functions to the buttons

Comment: As I said, please edit your question to state that, state what you want to happen, change the tags (this is javascript and jquery territory), and show what you tried so far to accomplish anything,.